# Next JS getStaticProps conditionally

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch

I'm building a small app in NextJS and was wondering if it's possible to conditionally fetch data?

For example: I have a small text input where the user can insert a name of a city, and I want the fetch to trigger only when there are 2 or more characters.

I have a state
`const [keys, setKeys] = useState(0);` and now I'm checking it using useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (keys.length > 1) {

        (async () => {
            const response = await fetch(
            `https://apiexample.com/country?name=${keys}`
            );
            const data = await response.json();
            setOptions(data.countries);
        })();
        } 
        return () => { 
            return setOptions([]);
        };

    }, [keys])
```

Now I want to fetch it using getStaticProps, but I can't manage to make it conditionally.

Comment: you simply cant. `getStaticProps`  fetch data at **build time** and pre-render a page. so you cant fetch data based on user inputs